# AS3 - How to create a new MovieClip from externally loaded SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I am exporting my animated characters from Flash Professional as a SWF to externally load them into AS3. I do not want to export them as SWC's because I have hundreds of these characters and only a small portion of them will be used at a given time.

It seems impossible to create multiple of these character MovieClips from the same loaded SWF since they are not SWC's I have no ActionScript linkage to be able to say

```
var myClip:MovieClip = new MyMovieClip();
```

I need to be able to make separate MovieClips from this same loaded character SWF. I essentially want to be able to say

```
var newMovieClip:MovieClip = otherMovieClip.clone();
```

Can this be done?

Comment: separate movieclip is not the same as a clone of movieclip:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you be able to try this:

`var newMovieClip:MovieClip = new (otherMovieClip as Object).constructor()`

or

```
var className:String = getQualifiedClassName(otherMovieClip);
if(className)
{
    var _class:Class = getDefinitionByName(className);
    if(_class)
    {
        newMovieClip = new _class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever. I hadn't seen the first option before. The second option throws an error if you don't have the class in your library linkage.

Comment: Then you give the application context from where the class definition should be taken.  Check documentation.